# mysql get rows up to a given column attribute

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of jobs

```
jobid priority (abbreviated here)
```

New job come into this table and they get reordered based on  the priority and high priority jobs get executed first. I want to know how many jobs are ahead of me given my job id.How do I write a query for this. I am using PHP, i can even do processing after the fact, but the problem is how do I get all the rows ordered by priority up to my jobid?

sample data

```
jobid priority (assume small number is high priority here)
--------------
 6     1
 4     1
21     1
14     1
16     2
 7     2
```

I want to get all the jobs before jobid 16. How do i do that.

some thing like

```
select * from jobs order by priority asc,start_time and stop when id touches 16
```

Comment: For two job IDs with duplicate priority, how are they ordered?

Comment: @MarcusAdams, it looks like ties are broken with `start_time` based on his example. (At least, the's the assumption I made in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE priority < (SELECT priority FROM tbl WHERE jobid = 16)
```

Comment: The example works only if i want to know how many jobs or before priority x. But that's not what I wanted. How about if i want to find how many jobs are before jobid 14

Comment: `= 16` is of course just a placeholder, if you need jobid = 14 just change that oO

Comment: @kiran, isn't it obvious that his 16 is just an example, just like your 16 was in your question?

Comment: Its obvious. Now use the same query for job id 14. SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE priority < (SELECT priority FROM tbl WHERE jobid = 14). The result of sub-query is 1 and I get all the jobs of priority < 1 which does not give me any jobs. Hope you understood that

Comment: Than just change `<` with `<=`

Comment: if change it to <=, i will get the jobs that are below the current row that have the same priority. lets say if the priority is 1 1 2 2 2, if i want to get the number of jobs before the 2nd-2 (which should give me (1 1 2), <= would also return the next 2. You might say this is just 1 row. But in my case the number of items in the table at any given time are around 200 with only 3 priorities

Comment: @kiran, look at my answer again. It shows you how to only get the rows below the one you want, including the ones where the priority is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You are ordering by `priority` and `start_time`, so you need to find out what the priority and start_time of the particular record is first.

```
SELECT priority, start_time FROM jobs
WHERE jobid = 16 
LIMIT 1
```

Save these results. You'll use them in the query that actually selects the rows you want:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs
WHERE priority < {PRIORITY_16}
  OR (priority = {PRIORITY_16} AND start_time < {START_TIME_16})
ORDER BY priority, start_time
```

In the above query, replace `{PRIORITY_16}` and `{START_TIME_16}` with the values you retrieved from the first query.

Instead of using two queries like above, you can use one query with three subqueries, but that will result in four actual queries. This is how you'd do that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM jobs 
WHERE priority < (SELECT priority FROM tbl WHERE jobid = 16)
  OR (priority = (SELECT priority FROM tbl WHERE jobid = 16)
     AND start_time < (SELECT start_time FROM tbl WHERE jobid = 16))
ORDER BY priority, start_time
```

Comment: This does not work Ben. The start time of a job that's higher up in the table might be greater than than the one that's lower. These jobs are not permanent in order. They can be changed in priority and then that the job moves higher or lower. So for my query the only thing that i know is my job id. I want what are all the jobs before me when ordered by priority. the priorities are not unique to a job.There can be 10000 jobs with only 4 priorities 1,2,3,4 in the system.

Comment: @kiran, check what it's doing again, your objections aren't correct. This will return *everything* of a higher priority, regardless of it's start_time. It will also return everything of *equivalent* priority that has a newer start time. This combination is *precisely* the set of all rows above the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In case you like JOINs (which sometimes optimize better) over subqueries:

```
SELECT jobs.*
FROM jobs
JOIN jobs j2
ON j2.jobid = 16
AND ((jobs.priority < j2.priority) OR
  (jobs.priority = j2.priority AND jobs.start_time < j2.start_time))
ORDER BY jobs.priority, jobs.start_time
```

Replace `16` with whatever job ID you're trying to return the results for.

Comment: Marcus, the start time of a previous job can be higher than the lower job. It went up higher in the table because the priority was increased so your solution did not work here

Comment: +1, I think this is the best solution (yes, including compared to mine)

Comment: @kiran, sorry, I forgot the order clause. I've updated the query. It should no order properly.